# How to Use TextView's "setMarkedText:selectedRange:" method in ios 4.3?

Tags: ios

In 4.3, there's no such method, there's only "setSelectedRange" method,

the "setMarkedText:selectedRange:" only in ios 5.0 and upper.

It's really a problem for me.

Comment: Don't support iOs 4.3 =) It is too old.

Comment: [The documentation says `setMarkedText:selectedRange:` has been available since iOS 3.2.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009415-CH1-SW15)  What happens when you try to use it?

Comment: The fact is that under ios 4.3, the UITextView doesn't confirm to the protocol "UITextInput".